A conjecture on the scheme-theoretic image of a moduli map
Let $K/\mathbb{Q}_p$ be a finite extension with residue field $k$, and let $K'/K$ be a finite tamely ramified Galois extension with residue field $k'$. Let $E/\mathbb{Q}_p$ be a sufficiently large finite extension with ring of integers $\mathcal{O}$ and residue field $F$. Let $S_A = (W(k') \otimes{\mathbb{Z}_p} A)[[u]]$ for a $p$-adically complete $\mathcal{O}$-algebra $A$.
Consider the moduli stack $\mathcal{C}{2,1,K'}$ over $\text{Spf } \mathcal{O}$ of rank 2 Breuil-Kisin modules of height at most 1 with descent data from $K'$ to $K$. Let $\mathcal{R}{2,K'}$ be the moduli stack of rank 2 étale $\varphi$-modules with descent data from $K'$ to $K$. There is a natural morphism $\mathcal{C}{2,1,K'} \rightarrow \mathcal{R}{2,K'}$ given by inverting $u$.
Let $\mathcal{Z}{2,K'}$ be the scheme-theoretic image of this morphism. For a tame inertial type $\tau$ of $I(K'/K)$, let $\mathcal{Z}{\tau}$ be the scheme-theoretic image of the restriction of this morphism to the substack $\mathcal{C}{\tau, \text{BT}}$ of $\mathcal{C}{2,1,K'}$ corresponding to potentially Barsotti-Tate representations of type $\tau$.
Is the following true: The stacks $\mathcal{Z}{2,K'}$ and $\mathcal{Z}{\tau}$ are generically reduced. More precisely, for each irreducible component $\mathcal{Z}'$ of $(\mathcal{Z}_{2,K'})F$ (resp. $(\mathcal{Z}{\tau})_F$), the local ring at the generic point of $\mathcal{Z}'$ is a field.
To investigate this, I'm considering several approaches. First, I think analyzing the versal rings of the stacks $\mathcal{Z}{2,K'}$ and $\mathcal{Z}{\tau}$ at their generic points could be fruitful. By looking into the structure of these rings, we might glean insights into the nature of the singularities. Exploring the local models of the stacks $\mathcal{C}{2,1,K'}$ and $\mathcal{R}{2,K'}$ also seems promising. Perhaps by understanding the singularities of these local models, we can connect them to the singularities of the scheme-theoretic images.
Any other thoughts or ideas?

This is hard to read, i think a bunch of subscripts are misformatted.
